# Why bottleneck structure is slower and costs more memory when training a network comparing to standard convolution?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I'm using vnet to train a model. I want to train the model faster with less memory. So I replaced the standard 3x3 convolution to a combination of [1x1, 3x3 , 1x1] convolutions. The first 1x1 conv will reduce the channel to 1/N to reduce memory cost. The code is as follows.

The first two classes is bottleneck structure and standard convolution. When I replace the standard convolution to bottleneck structure, **although the model size and flops decrease, the real GPU memory cost and training time increase.**

For example, I got :

```
Using standard convolution..........
Total parameters : 10,052,609 float, model size : 39,268.00390625M
191.78 GFLOPs
end : 10.62517523765564s
Max memory allocated : 3818.25341796875M

Using bottleneck...........
Total parameters : 1,145,061 float, model size : 4,472.89453125M
16.05 GFLOPs
end : 16.890745162963867s
Max memory allocated : 4408.35107421875 M
```

However, in inference stage, the bottleneck structure can accelerate the network to some extend.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to accelerate the network both in training and inference stage?

Code :

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

def groupNorm(channel, num_groups=16):
    return nn.GroupNorm(num_groups=num_groups, num_channels=channel)

Norm = nn.BatchNorm3d

BottleNeck_Ratio = 4


class BottleNeck(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, drop, stride=1, padding=1, N=BottleNeck_Ratio):
        super(BottleNeck, self).__init__()

        self.conv_1 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels // N, kernel_size=1, stride=1)
        self.conv_2 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels=out_channels // N, out_channels=out_channels // N, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                stride=stride, padding=padding)
        self.conv_3 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels=out_channels // N, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=1, stride=1)

        self.norm = Norm(out_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.drop = nn.Dropout3d(drop)

    def forward(self, input):
        x = self.conv_1(input)
        x = self.conv_2(x)
        x = self.conv_3(x)
        return self.drop(self.relu(self.norm(x)))


class CBR(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, drop, stride=1, padding=1):
        super(CBR, self).__init__()

        self.conv = nn.Conv3d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                              stride=stride, padding=padding)
        self.norm = Norm(out_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.drop = nn.Dropout3d(drop)

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.drop(self.relu(self.norm(self.conv(input))))


ConvBnReluDrop = BottleNeck


class ResidualDown(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, drop, conv_nums, down=True):
        super(ResidualDown, self).__init__()

        if down:
            self.down = ConvBnReluDrop(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, drop=drop)
        else:
            self.down = ConvBnReluDrop(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, drop=drop)

        self.convs = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(conv_nums):
            self.convs.append(ConvBnReluDrop(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, drop))

        self.has_down = down

    def forward(self, x):
        # downsample
        res = self.down(x)
        # convolution
        out = res
        for conv in self.convs:
            out = conv(out)
        # residual
        return out + res


class ResidualUp(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, drop, conv_nums, up=True):
        super(ResidualUp, self).__init__()
        if up:
            self.deconv = nn.ConvTranspose3d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        else:
            self.deconv = ConvBnReluDrop(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, drop=drop)

        self.convs = nn.ModuleList()
        self.convs.append(ConvBnReluDrop(2 * out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, drop))
        for i in range(conv_nums - 1):
            self.convs.append(ConvBnReluDrop(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, drop))

    def forward(self, big, small):
        x = self.deconv(small)
        # interpolate to prevent size not match
        x = F.interpolate(x, big.size()[-3:], mode='trilinear', align_corners=False)
        # save x as residual, [out_ch]
        res = x

        # skip connection, concat and conv to small's channel
        # [2*out_ch] => [out_ch]
        x = torch.cat([big, x], 1)
        for conv in self.convs:
            x = conv(x)
        return x + res


class VBNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch=1, nclass=1, drop=0.01, level=5, bn='batch', bottleneck=False):
        super(VBNet, self).__init__()
        # levels
        self.level = level
        # Normalization layer
        global Norm
        if bn == 'batch':
            Norm = nn.BatchNorm3d
        elif bn == 'group':
            Norm = groupNorm
        # elif bn == 'syncbn':
        #     Norm = SyncBN3d
        else:
            raise Exception("Error for bn")

        global ConvBnReluDrop
        if bottleneck:
            ConvBnReluDrop = BottleNeck
        else:
            ConvBnReluDrop = CBR


        # down 2
        self.downs = nn.ModuleList()
        self.downs.append(ResidualDown(in_ch, 16, 3, drop, 1, False))
        self.downs.append(ResidualDown(16, 32, 3, drop, 2))

        # down layers
        channels = 32
        for i in range(level - 2):
            self.downs.append(ResidualDown(channels, channels * 2, 3, drop, 3))
            channels *= 2

        # up layers
        self.ups = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(level - 3):
            self.ups.append(ResidualUp(channels, channels // 2, 3, drop, 3))
            channels = channels // 2

        # up 2
        self.ups.append(ResidualUp(channels, channels // 2, 3, drop, 2))
        channels = channels // 2
        self.ups.append(ResidualUp(channels, channels // 2, 3, drop, 1, False))
        channels = channels // 2

        # classifier
        self.classifier = nn.Conv3d(channels, nclass, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x): # 4,472.89453125M
        outs = []
        for layer in self.downs:
            x = layer(x)
            outs.append(x)

        small = outs[-1]
        for i in range(len(self.ups)):
            layer = self.ups[i]
            big = outs[self.level - i - 2]
            small = layer(big, small)

        out = self.classifier(small)
        return out

def get_net_size(net):
    params = list(net.parameters())
    k = 0
    for i in params:
        l = 1
        for j in i.size():
            l *= j
        k = k + l
    s = ("Total parameters : {:,} float, model size : {:,}M".format(k, k * 4 / 1024))
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # count_ops is taken from : https://github.com/1adrianb/pytorch-estimate-flops/blob/master/pthflops/ops.py
    import count_ops
    import os
    import time

    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1'

    # 4003728896
    print("Using standard convolution..........")
    a = torch.randn(6, 1, 32, 128, 128)
    net = VBNet(bn='batch', bottleneck=False)
    print(get_net_size(net))
    print(count_ops(net, a))

    net = net.cuda()
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(10):
        a = torch.randn(6, 1, 32, 128, 128).cuda()
        b = net(a)
        b.sum().backward()
    print('end : {}s'.format(time.time() - start))
    print("Max memory allocated : {}M".format(torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated(0) / (1024.**2)))

    # 4543840768 4622491136
    print("\nUsing bottleneck...........")
    # torch.cuda.reset_max_memory_allocated(0)
    a = torch.randn(6, 1, 32, 128, 128)
    net = VBNet(bn='batch', bottleneck=True)
    print(get_net_size(net))
    print(count_ops(net, a))

    net = net.cuda()
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(10):
        a = torch.randn(6, 1, 32, 128, 128).cuda()
        b = net(a)
        b.sum().backward()
    print('end : {}s'.format(time.time() - start))
    print("Max memory allocated : {} M".format(torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated(0) / (1024.**2)))
```

Comment: About the GPU memory, you [should not use `nvidia-smi`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark/issues/182#issuecomment-440583483). Use [`torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated()`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark/blob/55796a04ea770029a80cf5933cc5c3f3f6fa59cf/maskrcnn_benchmark/engine/trainer.py#L109) instead?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I used the code to get memory usage. but the result still shows that when using bottleneck structure, more memory  is needed to train the model.

Answer (score 0):

I compared three convolutions : standard convolution, bottleneck structure and separable convolution and got the performance results:

For standard Convolution :

```
Total parameters : 13920 float, model size : 54.3750M
2.75 GFLOPs, for input size : (6, 16, 32, 32, 32)
-------------------Train analyze----------------
total train time   : 8.0517 s
Total iteration    : 250
mean forward  time : 0.0003 s
mean backward time : 0.0007 s
Max memory allocated : 120.1846 M
-------------------Test  analyze----------------
total test time    : 7.6900 s
Total iteration    : 250
mean data     time : 0.0305 s
mean forward  time : 0.0003 s
Max memory allocated : 72.1826 M
```

For bottleneck :

```
Total parameters : 7872 float, model size : 30.7500M
1.56 GFLOPs, for input size : (6, 16, 32, 32, 32)
-------------------Train analyze----------------
total train time   : 8.7080 s
Total iteration    : 250
mean forward  time : 0.0009 s
mean backward time : 0.0016 s
Max memory allocated : 168.0767 M
-------------------Test  analyze----------------
total test time    : 8.8901 s
Total iteration    : 250
mean data     time : 0.0348 s
mean forward  time : 0.0008 s
Max memory allocated : 72.0728 M
```

For Separable Convolution :

```
Total parameters : 1088 float, model size : 4.2500M
0.23 GFLOPs, for input size : (6, 16, 32, 32, 32)
-------------------Train analyze----------------
total train time   : 8.3567 s
Total iteration    : 250
mean forward  time : 0.0009 s
mean backward time : 0.0014 s
Max memory allocated : 144.2021 M
-------------------Test  analyze----------------
total test time    : 7.9258 s
Total iteration    : 250
mean data     time : 0.0309 s
mean forward  time : 0.0008 s
Max memory allocated : 72.1992 M
```

We can see that the standard convolution is twice faster than bottleneck structure and separable convolution. And its memory cost is also not larger than other two methods.

I guess the reason could be that when forward or backward in training, the bottleneck and separable structure which have more convolution modules will **use more memory to save input for back propagation** and they also **do more convolution operation** than standard convolution. So either the memory cost nor speed of these two structure can surpass the standard convolution.

Another reason why separable convolution is slower could be that the cuDNN library dosen't directly support depthwise separable convolutions.

But these two structure **indeed reduce the model size dramatically** comparing to standard convolution, which is very useful for mobile device.

Code is following:

Three different convolutions.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import analyze_network_performance
import functools

Norm = nn.BatchNorm3d


class CBRSeq(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=1, N=2):
        super(CBRSeq, self).__init__()
        self.seq = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding),
            Norm(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.seq(input)


class BottleNeckSeq(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=1, N=2):
        super(BottleNeckSeq, self).__init__()
        self.seq = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels//N, kernel_size=1, stride=1),
            Norm(out_channels//N),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

            nn.Conv3d(in_channels=out_channels//N, out_channels=out_channels//N, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding),
            Norm(out_channels//N),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

            nn.Conv3d(in_channels=out_channels//N, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=1),
            Norm(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.seq(input)


class GroupSeq(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=1, N=2):
        super(GroupSeq, self).__init__()
        self.seq = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=in_channels, groups=in_channels,
                      kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding),
            Norm(in_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv3d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=1),
            Norm(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.seq(input)


def test_bottleneck():

    data_gen = functools.partial(torch.randn, 6, 16, 32, 32, 32)

    a = BottleNeckSeq(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

    b = CBRSeq(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

    c = GroupSeq(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

    print('BottleNeck Structure ....')
    analyze_network_performance(a, data_gen, train_time=250, test_time=250)

    print('\nStandard Convolution ....')
    analyze_network_performance(b, data_gen, train_time=250, test_time=250)

    print('\nSeparable Convolution ...')
    analyze_network_performance(c, data_gen, train_time=250, test_time=250)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_bottleneck()
```

`analyze_network_performance` code.

```py
import time
# count_ops is taken from : https://github.com/1adrianb/pytorch-estimate-flops/blob/master/pthflops/ops.py
from ops import count_ops
import torch
import numpy as np

def get_net_size(net):
    params = list(net.parameters())
    k = 0
    for i in params:
        l = 1
        for j in i.size():
            l *= j
        k = k + l
    s = ("Total parameters : {:} float, model size : {:.4f}M".format(k, k * 4 / 1024))
    return s

class Timer(object):
    def __init__(self, verbose=False):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.duration = 0

    def restart(self):
        self.duration = self.start_time = time.time()
        return self.duration

    def stop(self):
        return time.time() - self.start_time

    def get_last_duration(self):
        return self.duration

    def __enter__(self):
        self.restart()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.duration = self.stop()
        if self.verbose:
            print('{:^.4f} s'.format(self.stop()))


def to_cuda(data, device):
    if device < 0:
        return data
    else:
        return data.cuda(device)


def network_train_analyze(net, data_generate_func, cuda=0, train_time=10, forward_verbose=False):
    t1 = Timer(verbose=True)
    t2 = Timer(forward_verbose)
    t3 = Timer(verbose=False)
    if cuda >= 0:
        torch.cuda.reset_max_memory_allocated(cuda)
    forward_times = []
    backward_times = []
    with t1:
        for i in range(train_time):
            a = to_cuda(data_generate_func(), cuda)
            with t3:
                b = net(a)
                if forward_verbose:
                    print('forward  : ', end='')
            forward_times.append(t3.get_last_duration())

            with t2:
                b.sum().backward()
                if forward_verbose:
                    print('backward : ', end='')
            backward_times.append(t2.get_last_duration())
        print('total train time   : ', end='')
    print("Total iteration    : {}".format(train_time))
    print('mean forward  time : {:^.4f} s'.format(np.mean(forward_times[1:])))
    print('mean backward time : {:^.4f} s'.format(np.mean(backward_times[1:])))
    if cuda >= 0:
        print("Max memory allocated : {:^.4f} M".format(torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated(cuda) / (1024.**2)))


def network_test_analyze(net, data_generate_func, cuda=0, test_time=50, forward_verbose=False):
    t1 = Timer(verbose=True)
    t2 = Timer(verbose=forward_verbose)
    t3 = Timer(verbose=False)
    if cuda >= 0:
        torch.cuda.reset_max_memory_allocated(cuda)
    forward_times = []
    data_times = []
    with t1:
        with torch.no_grad():
            for i in range(test_time):
                with t3:
                    a = to_cuda(data_generate_func(), cuda)
                data_times.append(t3.get_last_duration())

                with t2:
                    net(a)
                    if forward_verbose:
                        print('forward  : ', end='')
                forward_times.append(t2.get_last_duration())
        print('total test time    : ', end='')
    print("Total iteration    : {}".format(test_time))
    print('mean data     time : {:^.4f} s'.format(np.mean(data_times[1:])))
    print('mean forward  time : {:^.4f} s'.format(np.mean(forward_times[1:])))
    if cuda >= 0:
        print("Max memory allocated : {:^.4f} M".format(torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated(cuda) / (1024.**2)))


def analyze_network_performance(net, data_generate_func, cuda=0, train_time=10, test_time=20, forward_verbose=False):

    print('============ Analyzing network performance ==============')

    print(get_net_size(net))

    net = to_cuda(net, cuda)
    a = data_generate_func()
    a = to_cuda(a, cuda)
    print(count_ops(net, a))

    print('-------------------Train analyze----------------')
    network_train_analyze(net, data_generate_func, cuda, train_time, forward_verbose)

    print('-------------------Test  analyze----------------')
    network_test_analyze(net, data_generate_func, cuda, test_time, forward_verbose)
```